# InputStream not clearing after being read

Tags: java, stream

I have the following code:

```
public class Interface {    
    public void exec(){            
        Scanner scanner = null;
        Integer count = 0;

        while( count < 4 ){               
            _inputStream.read();
            scanner = new Scanner( _inputStream );
            String inputLine = scanner.nextLine();
            _inputStream.reset();
            System.out.println( inputLine );
        }
        scanner.close();
    }

    public void setInputStream( InputStream inputStream ){
        _inputStream = inputStream;
    }
}
```

Which I'm trying to test with the following code:

```
public void testInterface() {
    Interface ui = new Interface();
    ui.exec();

    ui.setInputStream( new ByteArrayInputStream( "This is the first prompt".getBytes( Charset.defaultCharset() ) ) );   
    ui.setInputStream( new ByteArrayInputStream( "This is the second prompt".getBytes( Charset.defaultCharset() ) ) );  
    ui.setInputStream( new ByteArrayInputStream( "This is the third prompt".getBytes( Charset.defaultCharset() ) ) );           
    ui.setInputStream( new ByteArrayInputStream( "This is the fourth prompt".getBytes( Charset.defaultCharset() ) ) );
}
```

The output I would like to get is

```
This is the first input
This is the second input
This is the third input
This is the fourth input
```

but what I'm actually getting is

```
his is the first input
his is the first input
his is the first input
his is the first input
```

The problem, at least as far as I'm aware, is that the `_inputStream` is not being cleared in each iteration of the loop, meaning the `read()` function is returning immediately instead of waiting for the new stream of data. I'm resetting the stream after each reading though so I'm not sure why this should be the case.

How can I amend my code so that `_inputStream.read()` will wait for the user input every time the loop is run?

Comment: I'm surprised it even works. When you call exec(), you haven't called setInputStream() yet. You should have some `NullPointerException` (if _inputStream is not assigned elsewhere, we can't tell since you haven't shown us the part where it is declared)

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile. There is no _inputStream field, and we don't know what its initial value is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the method `exec()` you are calling `_inputStream.read()` which is blocking. But it doesn't mean the execution goes out of exec() at this stage! This is not something like a C# coroutine.

So actually `_inputStream.read()` is called against whatever instance of InputStream is assigned in _inputStream elsewhere and it prints the four lines of output before you have the chance to call `ui.setInputStream( new ByteArrayInputStream( .....`

So 4 times you read in the same InputStream and you reset it after reading it. Therefore you have the same 4 lines of output.

Answer (score 0):

Err, call exec() after you call setInputStream() each time?

This cannot possibly be be your real code.

Answer (score 0):

Also the reset-method will reset the stream back to where the last mark was was set or to the beginning, but does not take out the data in there.